# C# MongoDB .NET Driver DateDiff Two Date Fields In Document

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to query a MongoDB Collection where the date difference between two date fields, within each Document, is equal to 1 day.

I've tried using the MongoDB.Driver.Builders using the `Where` or `Eq` FilterDefinitions but cannot get it to work.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, is there a way to exclude the time portion so I'm just getting the difference between two dates?

Here is the code I have:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("local"); 
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testCollection"); 
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Exists("{$cond:[{$gte:[{$divide:[{$subtract:[DateField1,DateField2]},1000*60*60*24]},1]}]}"); 
var documents = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you add the code that doesn't work?

Comment: var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("local");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testCollection");

var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

var filter = builder.Exists("{$cond:[{$gte:[{$divide:[{$subtract:[DateField1,DateField2]},1000*60*60*24]},1]}]}");

var documents = collection.Find(filter).ToList();